# r - Create multiple dataframes for every rowname of an existing dataframe using information contained in other rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to create multiple data frames using the information contained in the rows of an existing data frame. The procedure should't be too hard, but it's not easy to describe succinctly. Take the following data frame:

```
B <- data.frame(Player=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","a","b","c","d","e"),
           Team=c("Red","Red","Light","Light","Blue","Blue","Red","Blue","Red","Blue","Light"),
           Day=c("Monday","Monday","Monday","Monday","Monday","Monday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday"),
           Result=c("Lose","Lose","Win","Win","Lose","Lose","Lose","Win","Lose","Win","Lose"))

B

   Player  Team     Day Result
1       a   Red  Monday   Lose
2       b   Red  Monday   Lose
3       c Light  Monday    Win
4       d Light  Monday    Win
5       e  Blue  Monday   Lose
6       f  Blue  Monday   Lose
7       a   Red Tuesday   Lose
8       b  Blue Tuesday    Win
9       c   Red Tuesday   Lose
10      d  Blue Tuesday    Win
11      e Light Tuesday   Lose
```

I need to create a new dataframe for every single `Player` (a, b, c, etc). The columns of the new data frames include the `Team`, the `Day`, the `Result`, and then one column per every other `Player` in the total pool, with values indicating whether that player was a team mate (1), was an opponent (-1) or didn't play at all that day (NA). The result looks like this:

```
Player  Day       Team  Result Team_mate_b Team_mate_c Team_mate_d Team_mate_e Team_mate_f
a       Monday    Red   Win    1           1           -1          -1          -1
a       Tuesday   Red   Lose  -1          -1           -1           1          NA
```

Any takes?

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse); df1 %>% mutate(Player = paste0("Team_mate_", Player), n = 1) %>% spread(Player, n)`

Comment: What @akrun suggested produced `NA` so add one line `df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0` and you get your result.

Comment: There should be 4 rows as Win and Lose are there for both 'Day's

Comment: Works better than what I imagined the outcome should be - thanks. In relation to the NAs, how do I distinguish between those who didn't play at all that day, and those who played but on the opposite team? If this new requirement doesn't have a quick solution, I can reformulate the question.

Comment: @NBK Please check the solution posted below

Answer (score 2):

If we want for each `unique` 'Player', then loop through them and convert to 'wide' format with `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    pull(Player) %>%
    unique %>% 
    map( ~ df1 %>%
               select(-Team) %>% 
               mutate(Player2 = Player, Player = .x)  %>% 
               filter(Player2 != .x) %>% 
               mutate(Player2 = paste0("Team_mate_", Player2), n = 1) %>% 
               spread(Player2, n, fill = 0))
```

Comment: Your first solution is better, because there the output indicates what team the player belonged to. Based on this second solution, I can't tell whether player a won or lost on Monday, and who her team mates were. That said, this second solution has the advantage of automatically creating a data frame for each player. Are there simple changes to improve this second solution?

Comment: @NBK  I am a bit confused about your expected output.  As I mentioned in the comments, how did you get only one combination of Win and Lose for Monday and Tuesday?  Can you update your expected output

Comment: You're right, it was a bit confusing. I updated the question. Basically, I need the column for each player to tell me whether that person was a team mate (1), an opponent (-1), or didn't play at all that day (NA).